# Посчитать сумму элементов массива, если в массиве есть неразрывный пробел

Tags: php, массивы

Как можно посчитать сумму элементов массива, если некоторые элементы имеют значения `&nbsp;`? Пытался убрать или отфильтровать эти значения, но никак не получилось. Пример массива:

```php
Array (
     ...
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 2
    [13] => 1
    [14] => 3
    [15] => &nbsp;
    [16] => &nbsp;
    [17] => 1
    [18] => &nbsp;
    [19] => &nbsp;
    [20] => &nbsp;
    ...
    )
```

Comment: array_sum() разве не справляется? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Все считается:

```
<?php

$d = array(
    "1" => "bar",
    "2" => "foo",
    "3" => "3" ,
    "4" => 2 ,
);

echo    array_sum($d); //выводит 5
```